# Using #ifdef preprocessor around virtual functions causes runtime error in program linked against libraries

Tags: c++, inheritance, preprocessor, virtual-functions

I was trying to use #ifdef preprocessor around virtual functions. A simplified version of code looks like following:

```
class Base
{
#ifdef ENABLE_FLAG
    virtual void function1();
#endif //ENABLE_FLAG

    virtual void function2();
    virtual void function3();
};

class Child : public Base
{
#ifdef  ENABLE_FLAG
    void function1() override;
#endif //ENABLE_FLAG

    void function2() override;
    void function3() override;
};
```

The code compiles fine. However, when my application is calling Child::function3(), it actually ended up calling Child::function2() for some reason. I think the preprocessor has messed up the virtual table some how.

I am running debug mode in visual studio 2017. I'm curious what is the cause of this runtime problem. Is this a compiler dependent behaviour?

Another interesting thing to note is that if I make sure ENABLE_FLAG is defined and remove the #ifdef clause in the Child class and keep the one in Base class, the compiler is actually throwing a compilation error. What difference does it make here?

UPDATE: This class is used both in a main program and in a library.

Comment: That would happen if you link objects (or libraries) that were not all compiled with the same `ENABLE_FLAG` setting - either defined or not defined.

Comment: If this is in a header file which is sometimes included with `ENABLE_FLAG` defined and sometimes without, that's a violation of the One Definition Rule (header version).

Comment: @aschepler I have ENABLE_FLAG defined in a macro which is loaded at the start of compilation in CMake file. Will this still cause the problem? ENABLE_FLAG should be consistent throughout the application.

Comment: Apparently it's not consistent, for whatever reason.

Comment: @JohnYang If you change whether or not ENABLE_FLAG is defined, does CMake rebuild **everything**? If not, there you go.

Comment: @aschepler I checked settings in visual studio, the ENABLE_FLAG is definitely defined in the preprocessor definitions.

Comment: @JaMiT I am doing clean build always when testing this (even removing the whole build folder and regenerate), and the problem is still there. But one thing to note is that I am building this as a library which is linked by another main application. Maybe I need to make sure the main application also sets ENABLE_FLAG.

Comment: You should ensure that your flag is visible. One way to do that would be to use use a pragma to generate a warning or an error so that you can confirm that it works as expected (the file is compiled and the expected value is used). Many things can go wrong as symbol can be defined at many locations and might be visible or not.

Comment: @JohnYang *"Maybe I need to make sure the main application also sets ENABLE_FLAG."* -- get rid of "maybe".

Comment: Unless you have a good reason to use conditionnal compilation, it it might be preferable to have only one version.

Comment: I changed the title and added an update to make it clear the question is about this behavior in a class shared between a main program and libraries.  This was only reflected before in comments.  Now the question is on topic, useful, and the answers are good for others too.  Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual functions are listed in a per-class table - the `virtual function table` or `vtable` - each instance of the class contains a pointer to this table which itself contains pointers to each of the virtual functions for that class, *in the order in which they are listed in the class declaration* (*).  (There are plenty of tutorial articles and videos that describe virtual tables if you want to look.)

So if you compile *part* of your program with that `#ifdef` enabled and another *part* of your program with that `#ifdef` *not* enabled - there will be a different number of virtual functions that the different parts see, and the *vtables will be different*.  Which is not supposed to happen, and leads to the problem you're seeing.

So don't do that.  You're violating a very strict rule of C++ called `ODR` or ["One Definition Rule"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).  Everything is up in the air if you do that - i.e., anything and everything can go wrong.

(Odd thing about the ODR: for such a very strict crucial rule, the compiler (i.e., compilation system as a whole) is not required in any way to tell you you've violated it.  So, really, *don't*.

By the way, all libraries and the main program must see the same class declaration! That stuff above about the ODR? The C++ standard doesn't know about "libraries" - static, dynamic, or otherwise. For it there are only programs and compilation units. (These "library" things are just a convenience the compilation systems provide for us.) So all the rules apply across entire programs - and the ODR is the one that will most often bite you here! (As you have just discovered...)

(*) To a first approximation, not including multiple inheritance ...

Comment: This answers my 2nd questions I believe. For my first question, I have ENABLE_FLAG defined in a macro which is loaded at the start of compilation in CMake file. Will this still cause the problem? ENABLE_FLAG should be consistent throughout the application.

Comment: @JohnYang - Apparently it isn't consistent.  You should probably check that in your build system.  Are you building this into both a library and a program that links against the library, with different settings for the flag?  Does it still happen if you do a clean build?

Comment: Yes I am building this as a library which is linked by another main application. So are you suggesting I have to set my main application with the same ENABLE_FLAG setting? I do clean build always when making changes.

Comment: @JohnYang - absolutely yes - library and main program must see the same class declaration!  That stuff in my answer about the ODR?  The C++ standard doesn't know about "libraries" - static, dynamic, or otherwise.  For it there are only programs and compilation units. (These "library" things are just a convenience the compilation systems provide for us.) So all the rules apply across entire programs - and the ODR is the one that will most often bite you here!  As you have just discovered ...